How to sanely make a handful of résumés?
I need to make résumés for a small group of people, and I have their data:

Name
Education

... and so on.
Should I simply make a macro (I can do that) or would it be better to invoke something like simplecsv or odsfile?

This is such a specific request with so little background that it is really impossible to say. It's a lot like saying "which is better—salt or pepper?" SE is really about helping people to solve specific problems with things they've already tried, rather than about providing opinions. What have you tried already?
